# Gradle multimodule project build in IntelliJ - relation between artifacts and wars

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

I'm facing some problems with my multimodule project gradle build in IntelliJ. My gradle build works correctly, but IntelliJ is not picking it up as it should causing my development cycle to slow down drastically.

I have this dependency setup between my projects (5 projects, 3 wars, shared has my model etc. common-web has the common web components)

```
TD (war) -> common-web
CP (war) -> common-web
CP (war) -> Shared
Web (war) -> common-web
Web (war) -> Shared
Shared
common-web
```

With the following structure:

```
|- TD
|- Web
|- Shared
|- common-web
|- CP
| settings.gradle
| build.gradle
```

I have one gradle build file and one gradle settings file.

```
include 'TD', 'CP', 'Web', 'Shared', 'common-web'

allprojects {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 8

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '1.11'
    }

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    dependencies {
       // dependencies...
    }
}
project(':CP') {
    apply plugin: 'war'
    dependencies {
       // dependencies...
        compile project(':shared')
        compile project(':common-web')
    }
}
project(':web') {
    apply plugin: 'war'

    dependencies {
       // dependencies...

        compile project(':common-web')
        compile project(':shared')
    }
}
project(':shared') {
    dependencies {
       // dependencies...
    }
}
project(':TD') {
    apply plugin: 'war'
    dependencies {
       // dependencies...
       compile project(':common-web')
    }
}
project(':common-web') {
    apply plugin: 'war' // needed to allow the providedComp

    dependencies {
       // dependencies...
    }
}
```

Is there a way I should configure the gradle idea plugin to allow this to be build correctly? have found the make button does not work like I think it should work, ignoring the compile errors in the modules etc. I see that in the root of the project, IntelliJ creates a folder classes/artifacts and does not use the (correct) build in the module/lib folder.

The errors I'm seeing is the wrong include of the jars. For example the web project has a dependency to the TD project, which is defined nowhere.

Is this a bug in the gradle plugin of IntelliJ or am I doing something I shouldn't?

Comment: I've abandoned using `idea` plugin some time ago. Currently I use gradle wrapper only and import projects to Idea pointing to the wrapper - everything works fine then. You may prepare a minimal working example illustrating the problem on GitHub and I may try if I have same problems.

Comment: due to the nature of my project, I cannot publish this online, but I'll try to create a test setup and reproduce my problem and post this on github

Comment: I created a stripped down version of my project and build everything from scratch and my dependencies are configured correctly now. Still this is different than when I'm coding. Could you elaborate on your way of working with gradle wrapper?

Comment: There are many different ways for importing project into IntelliJ. You can generate project files with `idea` plugin, use local gradle distribution or use gradle wrapper. I've abandoned using `idea` plugin because of many different problems. Instead I switched gradle wrapper which guarantees the same gradle version on every workstation and is imported to IntelliJ easily. Would like to know anything else?

Comment: I'm using the gradle wrapper now, works better, not perfectly, but better :)

Comment: Facing the same issue again, the jar's in the war aren't complete, resources missing, using gradlew...